# Why do I have to explicitly define a method provided by an inhereted class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, diamond-problem

Consider the following:

```
#include <string>

struct animal
{
public:
    virtual std::string speak() = 0;
};

struct bird : public animal
{
public:
    std::string speak()
    {
        return "SQUAK!";
    }
};

struct landAnimal : public animal
{
    virtual int feet() = 0;
};


struct sparrow : public bird, public landAnimal
{
    int feet() { return 2; }
    // This solves it, but why is it necessary, doesn't bird provide this?
    // std::string speak(){ return this->speak(); } 
};

int main()
{
    sparrow tweety = sparrow();
}
```

Compiling it, you'll get:

```
1>ex.cpp(35): error C2259: 'sparrow': cannot instantiate abstract class
1>  ex.cpp(35): note: due to following members:
1>  ex.cpp(35): note: 'std::string animal::speak(void)': is abstract
1>  ex.cpp(10): note: see declaration of 'animal::speak'
```

Why do you need the commented method to get it to compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because, unlike what you tagged, you *don't* have diamond inheritance. Your `sparrow` is two `animal`s, and only one of them is made concrete by `bird`. The other one, inherited through `landAnimal`, is not.

What you need to obtain an actual diamond is virtual inheritance, but as you'll find out it comes with an extensive list of caveats.

On a side note, as [Martin Bonner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771073/martin-bonner) rightfully points out:

> It's probably worth pointing out that the "fix" isn't a fix at all. Any call to `sparrow::speak()` will cause infinite recursion. It would need to be `std::string speak() { return Bird::speak(); }`.

Comment: I find it funny that despite the name, the dreaded "diamond problem" is that one *doesn't* actually have a diamond (object-wise).

Comment: @StoryTeller is it? I seemed to understand that the diamond problem is the whole host of weirdness that pops up once virtual inheritance is on the table :p

Comment: IIRC the standard presentation of the diamond problem is that multiple inheritance can add ambiguity when the two direct bases share a common base class themselves. Virtual inheritance is  then presented as the solution *to that*. The fact it causes other problems should probably have name of its own :)

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that the "fix" isn't a fix at all.  Any call to `sparrow::speak()` will cause infinite recursion.  It would need to be `std::string speak()  { return Bird::speak(); }`